# User Table In tempdb?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-administration

I am getting low disk space on production database server with SQL Server 2008 R2. The `tempdb` size has increased to 51G. It contains static tables, I mean when I look at tables in `tempdb` it has multiple number of tables. Most of these tables had 0 records but in two of the tables

```
select COUNT(*) from t102523_2E2CF266AB2F457E888427A000F5D2F3; --820310

select COUNT(*) from t102523_BB4717747002489CBD001E91669C3967; --1051323
```

I want to know why and on which scenario these tables gets created.I know if I restart the server disk space will get released. I also want to track on which scenario or action this has occurred. This issue has become normal once in a month.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can't tell you how those tables got created. You'll need to check the code of any 3rd party or other applications you're running, or ask your fellow developers / DBAs if they created these specific objects for a reason. SQL Server does not just automatically create user tables in `tempdb` unless you tell it to.

You may be able to find who created these tables in the default trace, if they were created recently enough:

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT ObjectName, HostName, ApplicationName, LoginName, StartTime
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT) AS t
WHERE DatabaseName = N'tempdb'
AND ObjectName LIKE N't102523[_]%'
AND EventClass = 46 AND EventSubClass = 0
--AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE name = t.ObjectName)
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

No luck? [Try reading the log directly](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10764/1186).

Still no luck? You may want to check if any user tables exist in the `model` database, and chase those culprits down, because anything you create in `model` will end up in `tempdb` as well on subsequent restarts.

If you can't locate the cause, you could [run a server-side trace](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72363/) (not actively run a trace in Profiler), capturing `object:created` and filtering to tempdb and `where name not like '#%';`. You could also consider [Extended Events](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822788(v=sql.100).aspx), DDL triggers, Audit, etc.

Comment: As it is not frequent , it happens once in a month. Can I use audit for this on tempdb. Will audit will solve my prob.

Comment: @Nitesh yes, I think you could use audit for this, but a server-side trace (as long as it is lightweight!) or extended events perhaps seem like much simpler ways to capture this activity.

Comment: Also can I drop these tables? Will it impact on performance or running databases?

Comment: @Nitesh nobody here can answer that question. If you don't know why the tables were created, how do you know they aren't being used by anyone? Of course, nobody *should* be relying on them, as they'll be dropped when the service restarts anyway, since tempdb is created from scratch every time. You may want to check if any user tables exist in the `model` database, and chase those culprits down, because anything you create in `model` will end up in tempdb on subsequent restarts.

Comment: @NiteshKumar And if the create date on the tables is recent it might show up in the [default trace](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10716/determining-how-a-schema-change-occurred/10718#10718)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a DDL trigger inside tempdb to trace who did it, something like this :

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.AuditCreateTable(
    LoginName sysname,
    DateCreation datetime2(0),
    App sysname,
    Host sysname,
    Info xml
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER AuditCreateTable ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.AuditCreateTable (LoginName, DateCreation, App, Host, Info)
    VALUES (SUSER_SNAME(), SYSDATETIME(), APP_NAME(), HOST_NAME(), EVENTDATA())
GO
```

Be aware that it will disappear if you restart the instance.

Comment: @Nitesh how does this help you find any information about the tables you've already created?

Comment: No this will not help in the tables already created but for further one as it happens randomly once in a month then trace or audit will be an overhead.It is quiet an alternative.

Comment: @NiteshKumar So your optimal solution is to manually create an audit table and DDL trigger in tempdb, every time you start the SQL Server service?

Comment: yep, sorry, I should have mentioned that : that's for the next month :)

Comment: Once I have track of these objects the n I can raise this issue to the concern person to manage or look after it, as currently I have nothing in hand to speak with.

Comment: Still not sure I understand the value of this solution. (1) you have to re-create this audit table and trigger every time you restart the service. (2) if SQL Server crashes or restarts, you'll have lost all of the data you collected previously. (3) this trigger isn't collecting any information that isn't already being collected for you in the default trace - and unless your system is extremely busy, that information will survive a lot longer (including multiple restarts).

Comment: I will add one more trigger on this . once an entry gets into this it will send me a mail notification. System crash is not an issue as it is on cluster. @Aaron , your solution is also good and standard one but my current concern is tracking ,so this is an alternative. I will use FQDN and insert the data into different database and hence my data will get preserve.

Comment: So how are you going to create a DDL trigger, a table, and a trigger on that table, every time SQL Server starts? Maybe you could use another trigger?

Comment: It is also production server , so restart of server is not so frequent and every thing will be in my concern.

Comment: @Nitesh you know that the answer you select is also representative of what other people, who may not be in the same circumstance as you, might think is the best solution, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41191/discussion-between-nitesh-kumar-and-aaron-bertrand)

Comment: I think it will be useful to trace drop table events.
This will give info before server restarts when these odd tables will be dropped.